# WebStorm not tabbing correctly on a single file

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm

For some strange reason, WebStorm has decided that all tabs typed in for a single file shall be single spaces, instead of the 4 the editor is set for.

I have checked, all my other source files are still working correctly.

Things I have tried:

1. Closing tab and reopening
2. Renaming the file
3. Restarting WebStorm
4. Restarting and clearing WebStorm cache
5. Rebooting machine
6. Deleting everything in the file and trying to tab, it still does it

Anyone else ever seen anything like this?  It's driving me nuts not to be able to tab!

Comment: Does it work in another file?

Comment: Yes all other files work fine, just this one is busted

Comment: Few ideas: **1)** You have `Detect and use existing file indents for editing` option enabled and it's somehow remembers those indents. Try disabling that option; **2)** Do you have any `.editorconfig` files in your project (even above the project root)? Maybe that file has special setting for this file (that's of course, if EditorConfig plugin is installed and enabled); **3)** Delete that file completely (from inside IDE); Create such file again outside of IDE and type some text there using proper indents. Open in IDE -- any better?

Comment: For your number 1 above, where is that option at.  I've looked for five minutes and can't find it.  Sounds promising to me

Comment: Found it and fixed it!  File->Settings, Editor->Code Style, it's on that tab.  If you post this as an answer to the question I will mark it the answer.  Thank you so much, didn't see that option before, this was driving me nuts!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ideas:

1. You have `Detect and use existing file indents for editing` option enabled and it's somehow remembers those indents. Try disabling that option at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Code Style`.
2. Try re-creating file from scratch (especially if you need option from #1 to be enabled):

   - delete that file completely (from inside IDE);
   - create such file again outside of IDE and type some code there using proper indents;
   - open in IDE -- any better?
3. Do you have any `.editorconfig` files in your project (even above the project root)? Maybe that file contains special settings for this file (that's of course if EditorConfig plugin is installed and enabled).